# no launcher activity found smartatch

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to run sample for Sony site.

I attached SmartExtensionAPI and SmartExtensionUtils. I used `Properties->Android->Library` and checked *is library*.

When I ran a sample (for example HelloWidget) on Eclipse, I get this error on the console:

```
HelloWidget] No Launcher activity found!
HelloWidget] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

But the installation is done... I can see the application is installed on my smartphone and I can see too on SmartConnect but not in the smartwatch.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

### EDIT:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name="com.example.sonymobile.smartextension.hellowidget.HelloWidgetPreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/preference_activity_title" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: You sure that `HelloWidgetPreferenceActivity` is in the correct package, i.e `com.example.sonymobile.smartextension.hellowidget.HelloWidgetPreferenceActivity`?

Comment: Could you try uninstalling the app (from device), clean build (from Eclipse) and then run/install (from Eclipse) it on your device.

Answer (score 0):

This is because no activity had set as a launcher to run when app is launched

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

no intent filter will be there in the code's manifest, just check it.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any errors but I can't see the app on my smartwatch.

Comment: @user2202087 share your manifest, where you have declared your `Activity`s.